# Why same path fails on testing and pass on browser

Tags: php, path, phpunit

[image: My code]

This code used to work, i changed nothing in this line and file structure still the same..
code used to work on both browser and with phpunit 
but now when i leave it as it's test fails

`PHP Warning:  Uncaught require(../config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

when i change the code to

```
$this->registry['config'] = require 'config/config.php';
```

test passes but can't find the file on the browser !

what is happening here ! 
here is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

Can you tell me what's wrong here ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$this->registry['config'] = require './config/config.php';
```

Just one point, and will work.

Comment: tests pass , but on browser i get `require(): Failed opening required './config/config.php'`

Comment: Do you use any autoloader or did you Define that config in another file ?

Comment: No, only here . I use psr-4 composer autoloading